# TSQL errors when calling a stored procedure with inline argument calculation

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to convert some oracle into SQL Server but I am having a problem calling a stored procedure. The following call:

```
Exec VEO_ADD_EVENT_NOTE p_DIVCODE, 
                        p_IncidentRef, 
                        p_UserID, 'A',  
                        format(getdate(),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm') + 
                        ' ' + Logged_FName + 
                        ' ' + Logged_LName + char(10) + 
                        'Template changed.';
```

produces this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TRAC-LEEDS-11, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'getdate'.

What is going on?

Comment: can you show the procedure definition ?

Comment: @Raj your edit has messed up the relationship between the code and the error message

Comment: How? Scrolling across to read and understand that code in a single line is hard. I have not changed your code, have I?

Comment: @Raj I can understand that but I think the error now appears on line 4 not on line one as the error message says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mucking around with this for a while I realised that

**In sql server you cannot call a procedure with an inline parameter calculation**

I really wish some of the documentation told you this in big bold letters!
As someone coming from non-sql languages that dont have so many quirks, this sort of stuff is just baffling.

If I change the code to:

```
declare @text nvarchar(Max)
set @text = format(getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm') + ' ' + Logged_FName + ' ' + Logged_LName + char(10) + 'Template changed.';

Exec VEO_ADD_EVENT_NOTE p_DIVCODE, p_IncidentRef, p_CompassUserID, 'A',  @text
```

then I start getting the other more expected errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server TRAC-LEEDS-11, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Logged_FName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server TRAC-LEEDS-11, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Logged_LName'.
```

Note this one actually means you need an '@'.  Another top quality error message

Comment: It is spelled out in the documentation, but perhaps not in an obvious way. I've wished for a "how to read this documentation" for the SQL Server docs many times, but it doesn't currently exist. Compare [`EXECUTE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) and [`SELECT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) and note the `SELECT` allows *expression* to appear, which can be almost arbitrary, `EXEC` only has options of *value*, *@variable* or *DEFAULT* and each of those is strictly defined.

Comment: At least the part about `Invalid column name` is pretty obvious, as variable names need to start with an `@` and as `Logged_FName` doesn't, the SQL engine thinks it must be a column - which is isn't. Thus the error.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I suppose except you also have to remember that when you declare a variable that is a cursor it **must not** have an @

Comment: @JonnyLeeds You are right about cursors. But I always thought the may have an `@` but don't require one?

Comment: Let me baffle you further with [this little gem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/834fa/1). Parameters without `@` is interpreted as strings.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson that's horrible!  Just discovered that myself - got my procedure converted and was wondering why I didn't have to use @ in the stored procedure calls